# Meaning of android studio checkboxes in properties window layout editor

Tags: android, android-studio, checkbox

Just updated to latest version (2.2) and saw the checkboxes that you can check in the properties window. There is three different options to choose from which two is pretty self explanatory, the checkbox that is checked and the one with minus in it. But what does the blank one mean? I tried all three and didn't notice any difference between the blank and minus. Probably not only specific to android studio but first time I se it.

[image: Blank checkbox]

[image: Minus sign]

[image: Checked checkbox]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be a bit late for an answer, but I've just had the same question while playing around with Android Studio. The meaning of the three states of the check boxes for boolean properties can be found by looking at the text view of the layout xml-file:

- checked -> property set "true"
- blank -> property set "false"
- minus symbol -> property unused, will not appear in the xml-file

Comment: Better late than never, thanks! But what do you mean by "property not used in code"? Is it used as a delete button of sorts for the property? Lets say you give the element a propery that is true, if you later decide that you do not want the property at all, do you set it to minus and the property and its code is removed from the xml?

Comment: Hi, yes you are right - if you set the property from 'true' or 'false' to 'minus' it will no longer appear in the xml-file. By the way likewise the non-boolean properties vanish in the code if no value is given. Of course this only holds for optional properties. I will edit the answer to describe it more clearly.